# How to navigate to external drive with JFileChooser on Mac

Tags: java, macos, swing, jfilechooser

I need to let my users select a folder on a external drive. On windows it woks fine but on Mac the pull down menu only shows the main drive.

I know that I can find external drives if I navigate to "Volumes" but I hate having to explain that to my users.

I have also tried using FileDialog but that brings up a new problem and that is that on Windows you can't select a folder. It must be a file.

Any idea on how I could accomplish this and that it works both on Windows and Mac?

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
String folderPath = "";
int returnValue = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    folderPath = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
    userPreferences.put("FILES_FOLDER", folderPath);
}
```

Comment: 1) *"the pull down menu only shows the main drive"* Was the drive attached before or after creating the file chooser? 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).